# What is the best way to model key in DynamoDB (Migration from RDS to NoSql)

Tags: oracle, amazon-dynamodb, sha, nosql

We are trying to migrate a Oracle based system to use DyanmoDBNoSQL.

Primary key in the Oracle is a complex object with multiple attributes (>6) and in DynamoDB there can be maximum 2 keys (Partition key and sort key) . How to model this in DynamoDB ?

We are considering generating a surrogate key using SHA 256 hashing. Is it a good design ?

Thanks,
Hareendra

Answer (score 1):

generate surrogate key is a good idea.

a good guide to design dynamodb tables is here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're describing a natural key rather than surrogate key. While I advise using surrogate key, you may not be able to avoid this. In this case, it *is* common practice in DDB data model design to compose composite keys as a function of many attributes, delineated by some separator. I haven't yet used >6 fields, but I don't see why not.

I'm an AWS employee and currently working on multiple systems in which we compose a partition key like `Field1Value::Field2Value::FieldValue3`. The size quotas on PK/SK wouldn't prevent you using 6 or more fields here.